# Javascript Atomics: Atomic.notify()/waitAsync() latency

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, web-audio-api

I'm updating some AudioWorklet code to replace postMessage()+transferables with SharedArrayBuffer+Atomics.  The worklet uses Atomics.notify() to trigger a task in the main thread which has set up an Atomics.waitAsync() listener to handle the task.  The old code posted a message to trigger the task and the main thread would post a message back with the results (using ArrayBuffer).  The new code puts the results into the shared memory.  The task gets triggered each process() call to the worklet, so at 48KHz it's about 2.5ms in between.

This all worked well with the old code, and the new code is working but not as well.  The latency between calling notify() and the waitAsync() firing seems quite a bit longer than that of postMessage() and the message being received. I don't have exact measurements, but often several process() calls have been made by the time waitAsync() wakes up.  I tried a hybrid approach where the worklet posts a message to trigger the task and the results are returned in shared memory and I'm no longer dropping requests.

I haven't been able to find anything definitive about notify()/waitAsync() latency though I expected it to be faster than postMessage().  Quite possibly a bug in my code, and I'm still debugging, but I'm asking if anyone can confirm or deny the differences in latency and if there are any particular strategies for minimizing latency with waitAsync().

FTR, this is being tested on Chrome 108 running on Debian Bullseye.  I can provide code if requested though it is pretty similar to the examples in the Atomics docs.

Thanks!

Comment: did you make any progress on this? I've stumbled on your post whild investigating Atomics as an alternative to postMessage.

Comment: @giohappy I didn't find a way to reduce the latency.  I ended up going with a different approach that still uses shared memory and atomics, but isn't as sensitive to latency.